# Footer not sticking properly in layout file

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, footer

so I want to have a footer on my website but it doesn't seem to stick to the bottom on my about page. Specifically, text will show up at the bottom, but if you add a background or something decorative, youll see that the footer is really in the middle of the page.

It works fine on my home page, but for whatever reason not on the about page.

I'm using Rails for the backend, and so the footer is in the layout file.

about page (where the footer isnt sticking)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- start page -->
<div class="window main-about">
   <div class="container" data-sr="flip 65deg over 2s">
     <!-- content -->
     <div class="row">
       <div class="content col-md-12 col-centered">
         <h1 class="headline"> Me in a Nutshell. </h1>

       </div>
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>
<!-- home -supporting -->

<div class="window">
  <div class="container full">
    <!-- row #1 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <h2 class="headline text-center grid-text"> Travelling. I like to do it. </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="abt-grid-1" class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- row #2 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div id="abt-grid-2" class="col-md-6"></div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <h2 class="headline text-center grid-text"> I go to Ryerson University. </h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- row #3 -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 ">
        <h2 class="headline text-center grid-text"> I'm also pretty awesome. </h2>
      </div>
      <div id="abt-grid-3" class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<!-- closing-supporting -->

</html>
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <title>Stories</title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,100,300" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:300,400,300italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- menu button -->
  <a id="simple-menu" href="#sidr"> <%= image_tag('https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/z2d/stories/menu-white.svg', width:'24px', alt:'Open', class:'menu-icon') %> </a>



<%= yield %>

<div id="sidr">
  <!-- Your content -->
  <ul>
    <li> <%= link_to "Home", '/home' %> </li>
    <li> <%= link_to "About", '/about' %> </li>
    <li> <%= link_to "The Lab", '/#' %> </li>
    <li> <%= link_to "Medium", '/blog' , :target => "_blank" %> </li>
  </ul>
</div>


<div id="footer">
Satchel (c) 2015
</div>

<!-- javascript -->
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

               <script>
               $(document).ready(function() {
                 $('#simple-menu').sidr();
               });
               </script>

              <script type ="text/javascript">
                 window.sr = new scrollReveal();
               </script>


</body>
</html>
```

pages.css.scss

```
// Place all the styles related to the Pages controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/
p{
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
display: block;
font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
font-size: 21px;
font-weight: 100;
height: 90px;
line-height: 30px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 0px;
margin-top: 30px;
text-align: center;}

p, h1 { margin: 0 }

.window {
    height:700px;
    width:100%;

    //border-top: solid 1px #000; //temp test
}
.full{
    width:100%;

}

.main-home {
 background: url('http://i58.tinypic.com/2v34yub.jpg') no-repeat center center;
 background-size:cover;
}

.main-about {
    background: url('https://static.pexels.com/photos/1440/city-road-street-buildings.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size:cover;

}


.secondary-home {
background:url('http://theabf.org/sites/default/files/nocredityosemite.jpg') no-repeat center center;
background-size:cover;
height:500px;
}

.window-support {
padding: 80px 0;
text-align: center;
}

.content {
    top:225px;
  position:relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

h1.headline {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 50px;
}

h2.headline {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 100;
font-size: 35px;
}


.btn.sharp {
border-radius:0;
border:none;
font-size: 14px;
}

.menu-icon {

    top:30px;
    left:30px;
    position:absolute;
    margin: 0;

}

.col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.halfBack {
    width: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    height:500px;

}

.grid-text {
    padding-top:205px;
}

#abt-grid-3 {
   background: url('https://paulkporterphotography.files.wordpress.com/2015/04/20141210-distillery-31.jpg') no-repeat center center;
   height:500px;
    background-size:cover;
}

#abt-grid-1{
    background:url('https://i0.wp.com/upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/1_yonge_street_toronto_winter_2010_panorama.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    height:500px;
    background-size:cover;

}
#abt-grid-2{
    background: url('http://ryersonbuilds.ryerson.ca/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/X6C61871.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    height:500px;
    background-size:cover;
}

#grid-long {
    background: url('https://ksulkski.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/istock_000000734318toronto_large.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    height:500px;
}



.footer {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border-top: solid 1px #F5F5F5;
    padding: 40px 0 30px 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: #ccc;
}
```

Comment: Which div is the footer div?

Comment: Sorry I removed it to upload the website with no footer, I just added it to the source code above. It still doesnt work though.

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understanding what you want correctly, then you should just use the css `fixed property.` Try something similar to this.

```
.myFooter {
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0px;
}
```

This will keep whatever tag you apply this class to position at the bottom of the view.

Comment: I tried, but I dont want a fixed one thats always in frame.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `position:absolute` to your footer with a width of 100% like this:

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle with the above code: http://jsfiddle.net/65sf2f66/45/

Comment: Sorry I should add, I've already done all of that stuff. I get it at the end of the frame on my 13" screen, but its in the middle of the page, even if I set it to absolute and do #footer {position:absolute; bottom:0px;}http://imgur.com/mskFWwu

Answer (score 0):

```
html {
position:relative;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}

body {
position:absolute;
min-width:100%;
min-height:100%;
}
```

That fixed it!